# Swift 2 - hitTest function - fatal error found nil

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, hittest

I have a bottom bar `UIView` inside an `UIScrollView` with two buttons in it. I am using the function `hitTest` in order to enable `user interaction` just for the two buttons.

The code works only if I touch the bottom bar however, when I touch any other part of the screen the app crashes saying:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

```
class HelpBarViewClass: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var backPageBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var nextPageBtn: UIButton!

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        let subview: UIView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)! // fatal error
        return subview == self.nextPageBtn || subview == self.backPageBtn ? subview :nil

    }

}
```

Why am I having this error?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to answer below the right code is:

```
class HelBarViewClass: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var backPageBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var nextPageBtn: UIButton!

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        let subview = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
        return subview == self.nextPageBtn || subview == self.backPageBtn ? subview : nil

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems obvious: `super.hitTest` returned `nil` but you force-unwrapped it. Don't do this.

Comment: you mean to remove `!` ?

Comment: @SNos Exactly. You can compare optionals to non-optionals.

Comment: I have tried but I get " Value of optional type `UIView?` not unwrapped"

Comment: Remove the explicit type, as well: `let subview = ...`

Comment: Thank you, is working.. 5  minutes left to accept the answer.